# Topology of sequentially open sets is sequential?

Tags: general-topology

Let $(X,\tau)$ be a topological space.  The collection of all sequentially open subsets of $X$ (i.e. the complements of the sequentially closed subsets) is itself a topology $\tau_\text{seq}$, equal to $\tau$ if $X$ is a [sequential space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_space), and a strictly finer topology otherwise. (See the wikipedia article for details.)

**Question:** Is $(X,\tau_\text{seq})$ a sequential space?

Comment: Isn't it immediate from the first characterization on the wiki page? $\tau_{seq}$ consists of all sequential open subsets of X.

Comment: It is not obvious.  Working equivalently in terms of closed subsets, what needs to be shown is that a subset that is sequentially closed in $(X,\tau_\text{seq})$ is closed with respect to $\tau_\text{seq}$, i.e., is sequentially closed in $(X,\tau)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $U$ is sequentially open with respect to $\tau_{\text{seq}}$, i.e., that every sequence converging in $\tau_{\text{seq}}$ to a point of $U$ is eventually in $U$. $\langle X,\tau_{\text{seq}}\rangle$ and $\langle X,\tau\rangle$ [have the same convergent sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_space#Properties_of_the_topology_of_sequentially_open_sets), so $U$ is sequentially open with respect to $\tau$ and is therefore in $\tau_{\text{seq}}$. Thus, $\langle X,\tau_{\text{seq}}\rangle$ is sequential.

Comment: Nice.  Thank you.

Comment: @PatrickR: You’re welcome.

Answer (score 2):

### Preliminaries:

Define, for a sequence $(x_n)$ in $X$ the tail filter of the sequence by $$\textrm{tail}(x_n) = \{A \subseteq X\mid \exists m\in \Bbb N: \{x_n: n \ge m\} \subseteq A\}$$

The definition of convergence says in essence that $x_n \to x$ for any topology $\tau'$ on $X$ iff $$\{O \in \tau'\mid x \in O\} \subseteq \text{tail}(x_n)\tag{0}$$

It is standard that $\tau_{\text{seq}}$ is defined by all sets $O$ such that

$$\forall x \in O: \forall (x_n) \subseteq X: (x_n \to_\tau x) \to O \in \textrm{tail}(x_n)\tag{1}$$

which are called the sequentially open sets w.r.t. the topology $\tau$. The [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_space#Topology_of_sequentially_open_sets) has a proof that this actually forms a topology on $X$ which clearly obeys $$\tau \subseteq \tau_{\text{seq}}$$ basically by the definition of convergence under $\tau$.

---

### Proof

Now suppose that $O$ is sequentially open for $\tau_{\text{seq}}$. We have to show $O$ is actually in $\tau_{\text{seq}}$. So let $x \in O$ be arbitrary and $x_n \to_{\tau} x$.

> **Fact**: $x_n \to x$ for $\tau_s$ as well: let $U$ be any open set in $\tau_{\text{seq}}$ containing $x$. Because $U \in \tau_{\text{seq}}$ and $x_n \to_\tau x$ *by definition* $U \in \textrm{tail}(x_n)$. But as $U \in \tau_{\text{seq}}$ was arbitrary containing $x$, indeed $x_n \to x$ for $\tau_{\text{seq}}$ ( we apply $(0)$ to $\tau_{\text{seq}}$) as required.

But as $O$ is sequentially open for $\tau_{\text{seq}}$, *by definition* again $O \in \textrm{tail}(x_n)$ and so $O$ (by $(1)$) is sequentially open for $\tau$,  i.e. $O \in \tau_{\text{seq}}$.

Which shows that $(X, \tau_{\text{seq}})$ is a sequential space by definition.

Comment: I realise this is essentially Brian's proof. But he does not show (the page he refers to also gives no proof, just a claim) why the topologies have the same convergent sequences and I do show *all* the necessary details. So I think this answer adds something.

Comment: Thank you.  Using the tail filter of sequences is a good way to organize the argument.

Comment: @PatrickR I hope it helps you.